# How to split a string based on comma, but not based on comma in double quote

Tags: raku

I want to split this string based on comma, but not based on the comma in double quote `"`:

```
my $str = '1,2,3,"4,5,6"';
.say for $str.split(/','/) # Or use comb?
```

The output should be:

```
1
2
3
"4,5,6"
```

Comment: Have you considered using a CSV module?

Comment: @melpomene CSV module works too!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

fast solution with `comb`, take anything but not `"` nor `,`
or take quoted string

```perl6
my $str = '1,2,3,"4,5,6",7,8';
.say for $str.comb: / <-[",]>+ | <["]> ~ <["]>  <-["]>+ / ;
```

Comment: it works well!  and `.say for $str.comb: / <-[",]>+ | '"' ~ '"'  <-["]>+ / ;` is the same thing. thanks @wamba.

Comment: Does this split `1,2,"abc,def""ghi,jkl",4,5` into the 5 fields `1`, `2`, `"abc,def""ghi,jkl"`, `4` and `5`?

Answer (score 9):

as @melpomene suggested, use the [Text::CSV](https://github.com/Tux/CSV) module works too.

```
use Text::CSV;

my $str = '123,456,"78,91",abc,"de,f","ikm"';
for csv(in => csv(in => [$str], sep_char => ",")) -> $arr {
   .say for @$arr;
}
```

which output:

```
123
456
78,91
abc
de,f
ikm
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
my $str = ‘1,2,3,"4,5,6",7,8’;

for $str.split(/ \" \d+ % ',' \"/, :v) -> $l {
  if $l.contains('"') {
    say $l.Str;
  } else {
    .say for $l.comb(/\d+/);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
"4,5,6"
7
8
```